# How to get a Taiwanese visa as a Pakistani citizen?

Tags: visas, china, taiwan, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national, have a company in China and my visa is Z category (**Chinese Work Visa**).  I want to travel to Taiwan for a business trip. How I can get the visa?

Comment: Were you able to get taiwanese visa in Shanghai ? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Are you currently residing in China? I wouldn't rely on your Chinese work visa to get you into Taiwan. You must get a visitor visa to enter Taiwan as there is no landing visa for Pakistan nationals. Previously Pakistan nationals acquired visas from Thailand, but I've heard a rumor they are no longer issuing for Pakistan nationals (if anyone can confirm this, that would be helpful). I would recommend you try and call the TECO in Hong Kong.

[Taiwan Info has information on visas and prices](http://www.taiwaninfo.org/apply.htm). A simple phone call can get you plenty of information.

Also, be sure to read the [BOCA information on visas](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=1305&CtNode=109&mp=2).

Answer (score 0):

The best way for Pakistanis , who are living in china based on working visa or studies visa or marriage visa, in all cases , they can apply visa only from Taiwan consulate / embassy in Hong Kong. Pakistanis are required visa before flying to Taiwan. So better you apply visa for Hong Kong first and then take visa for Taiwan. Most Probably you need invitation letter from Taiwan. Then you can apply visa form Taiwan consulate / embassy in Hong Kong.

Answer (score -2):

Hoilding Pakistani Passport are not eligible for any kind of visiting visa taiwan but they may apply for bussiness visa for business visa you may also require orgional copy of invitation letter you may also needed a OPV IPV or yellow card copy of tickets and then taiwan embassy will decided for how many days visa will give .

Comment: Please do not post emails on the site posts

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for this?